# Bootstrap row class for every 3 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to print 12 articles with pagers using bootstrap 3 theming:

```
@foreach($category->articles()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(12) as $article)

<div class="col-md-4">
<a href="/article/{{ $article->slug }}"><img class="img-responsive" src="/imagecache/mainart/{{ $article->image }}" /></a>
<p>{{ strip_tags(str_limit($article->body, $limit = 90, $end = '...')) }}</p>
</div><!--/col-md-4-->

@endforeach
```

However, i need to print div with class "row" with 3 columns inside.

```
array_chunk()
```

won't work in my case, because i am printing category related articles (one to many relationship) and it's object, not array.

Answer (score 10):

You have two options.

1. Use `array_chunk()` by converting your results to an array first
2. Use a custom function `break_array()` which allows you to do the same thing as `array_chunk()` but on objects

**Option 1:**

```
@foreach (array_chunk($category->articles()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(12)->toArray()['data'], 3, true) as $column)
      <div class="row">
          @foreach ($column as $article)
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <p>{{ strip_tags(str_limit($article['body'], $limit = 90, $end = '...')) }}</p>
              </div
          @endforeach
      </div>
@endforeach
```

**Option 2:**

Place this in a helper function somewhere in your application:

```
function break_array($array, $page_size) {

  $arrays = array();
  $i = 0;

  foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
    if ($i++ % $page_size == 0) {
      $arrays[] = array();
      $current = & $arrays[count($arrays)-1];
    }
    $current[] = $item;
  }

  return $arrays; 
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach (break_array($category->articles()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(12), 3) as $column)
      <div class="row">
          @foreach ($column as $article)
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <p>{{ strip_tags(str_limit($article->body, $limit = 90, $end = '...')) }}</p>
              </div
          @endforeach
      </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer

Comment: An excellent solution, I always make a fuss when my templates aren't as pristine as they could be!

Answer (score 7):

Create a count variable and echo a new `row` if the count is 0 or is divisible by 3.  I removed most of your code from the below example, you will have to add back your `foreach` loop as well as your `div` content.

```
    <?php 
    $count = 0;

    { //foreach as shown in question

        if($count==0 OR is_int($count/3)){
            echo '<div class="row">';
        } ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!--content-->
        </div>

        <?php if($count==0 OR is_int($count/3)){
            echo '</div>';
        }

        $count++;
    } //end foreach
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $num = 1;
    $breaker = 3; //How many cols inside a row? 

    foreach($a as $b) {

        if ($num == 1) echo '<div class="row">'; //First col, so open the row.

            echo '<div class="col-sm-4">Test</div>';

        $num++;

        if ($num > $breaker) { echo '</div>'; $num = 1; } // The num arrived at the break-point. Close the row!

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$c = 0;
$breaker = 3;

foreach ($cols as $col) {
    if ($c == 0 || $c%$breaker == 0) {
        ?><div class="row"><?php
    }

        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- content of column here -->
        </div>

        <?php

    $c++;
    if ($c%$breaker == 0) {
        ?></div><?php
    }
}   

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The one suggested by Dan will produce wrong separation into columns.
More correct variant will look like:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($rows_output as $row)
{

    if ($columns==1)
        $output .= '<li'.$active.'>'.$elem.'</li>';
    else {
        if ($count==0)
            $output .= '<div class="row">';
        if (is_int($count / $columns))
            $output .= '</div><div class="row">';

        $output .= "<div class='col-md-".(12/$columns)."'>".$elem."</div>";

        if ($count==count($rows_output))
            $output .=  '</div>';

    }    
    $count++;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//initialize count to 4.5

```
@foreach ($images as $image )

    @if($count==0  OR is_int($count/3))
        <?php echo '<div class="row">';?>
     @endif

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well" style="background:white;">
        <img src="{{ url('images/'.$image->filepath) }}" alt="" class="" height="100" width="100" ></br>

       {{ $image->title }}<br>
        {{$image->filepath }}
      </div>
    </div>

    @if($count==0 OR is_int($count/3))
        <?php echo '</div>' ;?>

    @endif

    <?php $count++;?>
@endforeach
```